# Any way to invoke a RecoveryCallback<T> in a RabbitTemplate send operation?

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-retry

I'm currently working with Spring AMQP version `1.3.6.RELEASE` and Spring Retry `1.1.2.RELEASE`. According to the Spring AMQP documentation section [3.3.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/amqp.html#template-retry) one can add retry capabilities by passing in a `RetryTemplate`.

Are there any existing capabilities to provide a `RecoveryCallback<T>` implementation? I was reviewing the [RabbitTemplate.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/main/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.java#L830) implementation and I couldn't find any.

The use case I'm considering is that if a `*Send()` execution fails because the broker is down I'd like to implement my own custom logic.

I understand that I could wrap the `convertAndSend()` call in my own `RetryTemplate` implementation and implement a `try { ... } catch (AmqpException e) { ... }` but I did not want to go down that road if Spring AMQP provided a cleaner implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct: there is no such an ability right now.

Feel free to raise a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP) and we'll address it soon.

Thanks.

And I think you go right way with a workaround: you really just use your own `RetryTemplate` instance with raw `RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend` invocation in the `doWithRetry` inline implementation.

Comment: Thank you, I've created JIRA Issue [AMQP-431](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-431) for this.